# IE 'allow blocked content' breaks up fonts

Tags: css, fonts

I've got some @font-face page generated on www.fontsquirrel.com

It works good, even on IE, but IE shows on it request to allow blocked content (font is alredy loaded when request appears, and it looks ok). When one will click 'allow' font just change to default or next on the list.

I havent changed it after generating on squirrel, so code must be ok. Any ideas what to do about it?

ps. its working the same with google fonts api.

Comment: no javascript is included etc, and I think most of visitors would click 'allow' and then all fonts just break up. Fonts loads normally, why IE 'touch it' and how to avoid that considering that I would like to add some js scripts to it in future.

Comment: you are testing this locally (your file system), so IE will ask you to confirm. Try to load it from a server and you will not see the warning